# Ajax Pagination Script Send Variable to php Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

```
 //index.php
<?php
    include("config.inc.php");
    if(!empty($_GET['email'])){
        $dude = $_GET['email']; // user email address to be gotten by javascript variable 
    // dude and sent to fetch_pages.php
        echo '<input type="text" style="display:none" id="hide" value="'. $dude .'" />';
        }
    $results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_registration_details");
    $get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records
    $item_per_page = 5;
    //break total records into pages
    $pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);   

    //create pagination
    if($pages > 1)
    {
        $pagination = '';
        $pagination .= '<ul class="paginate">';
        for($i = 1; $i< $pages; $i++)
        {
            $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }
        $pagination .= '</ul>';
    }

    ?>
    <?php
    /*
    * Ajax form submit
    */

    # request sent using HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH
    if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) ){
        if (isset($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['subject']) AND isset($_POST['message'])) {
            $to = 'your@mail.id';

            $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $sent = email($to, $email, $name, $subject, $message);
            if ($sent) {
                echo 'Message sent!';
            } else {
                echo 'Message couldn\'t sent!';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'All Fields are required';
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * email function
     *
     * @return bool | void
     **/
    function email($to, $from_mail, $from_name, $subject, $message){
        $header = array();
        $header[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
        $header[] = "From: {$from_name}<{$from_mail}>";
        /* Set message content type HTML*/
        $header[] = "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
        $header[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
        if( mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $header)) ) return true; 
    }

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Ajax Pagination</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var dude = document.getElementById("hide").value;//variable to be sent to fetch_pages //to present user email



    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load

        $(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {

            $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');

            var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
            var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need 

            $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class

            //post page number and load returned data into result element
            //notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
            $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':(page_num-1)}, function(){

            });

            $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to currently clicked element (style purpose)

            return false; //prevent going to herf link
        }); 
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="profiler.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    @import url("style2.css");
    </style>
    <link href="style5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body onload="profiler();">
    <div id="firstdiv">
    <p></p>
    <img id="image1" src="2347033609685.jpg"  alt="Profile Pic" height="170" width="180" />
    <table id="pname"><tr height="49"><td id="name">Richard Berry</td></tr>
    <tr  id="num"><td>08023818955</td><td width="400">Agent with homes and good event centres</td></tr>
    <tr height="20"><td width="200">Specialties: Event Centres / Venue</td>
    </tr></table>
    <table id="like"><tr><td width="6"></td><td width="31"><a href="get.php"><img src="2347033609685.jpg" height="27" width="27"  /></a></td>
    <td width="71"><a href="dude.php"><img src="yahoo2.PNG" height="27" width="27" /></a></td></tr>
    </table>
    <table id="pdetails"><tr><td width="200"><p  id="over" onclick="profilerr('pover');" ><button id="o">Overview</button></p></td>
    <td width="220"><p id="list" onclick="profile('plist');"><button id="l">Listings()</button></p></td>
    <td width="221"><p id="about" onclick="profiles('pabout');"><button id="a">About</button></p></td>
    </tr></table>
    <div id="pabout" style="display:none">
    <table>
    <tr><td id="name">About Richard Berry</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Firstly, there are two sets of people who come to this hall. The first set are those who just come to watch and/or charge gadgets and the second set are those who come to train.
    To the first set of people, we plead that you kindly stay in the waiting area when you visit the hall and far from tables especially when people are playing because most times it serves as a means of distraction and also playing on table is prohibited.
    Secondly, to the second set of people who are registered members of the team we are pleading that you should always be in complete sport outfit whenever you come for training and should avoid littering of the hall with nylons, papers, bottles e.t.c
    Most especially the new training timetable for the semester is below:</td></tr>
    </table></div>

    <div id="pover" style="display:none">
    <table>
    <tr><td id="name">About Richard Berry</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Firstly, there are two sets of people who come to this hall. The first set are those who just come to watch and/or charge gadgets and the second set are those who come to train.
    To the first set of people, we plead that you kindly stay in the waiting area when you visit the hall and far from tables especially when people are playing because most times it serves as a means of distraction and also playing on table is prohibited.
    Secondly, to the second set of people who are registered members of the team we are pleading that you should always be in complete sport outfit whenever you come for training and should avoid littering of the hall with nylons, papers, bottles e.t.c
    Most especially the new training timetable for the semester is below:</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="listl">Listings (2401) by Richard Berry</td></tr>
    </table></div>
    <div id="plist" style="display:none">
    <table>
    <tr><td id="listl">Listings(2401) by Richard Berry</td></tr>
    <tr></tr></table>

    <div id="results"></div>
    <?php echo $pagination; ?>
    </div>




    </div>  
    <div id="wrap">
    <p id="compdiv">Contact Supplier</p>
            <div class="alert">Hello</div>
            <form id="form" action="" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span id="spandisp">Name: * </span>
                        <input placeholder="Name" type="text" id="input" name="name" required>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span id="spandisp">Email: *                                                                          </span>
                              <input placeholder="Email address" id="input" type="email" name="email" required>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span id="spandisp">Subject: * </span>
                        <input placeholder="Subject" id="input" type="text" name="subject" required>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span id="spandisp">Message: *</span>
                        <textarea id="input2" placeholder="Type your message here...." name="message" required></textarea>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Send Message</button>
                </div>

            </form>
            <p>Note: * Fields are required</p>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>

//config.inc.php

    <?php

    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = '****';
    $db_name = '****';
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $item_per_page = 5;


    $connecDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name) or 
    die('could not connect to database');
        ?>

//fetch_pages

    <?php

    include("config.inc.php"); //include config file

        $item_per_page = 5;

    //sanitize post value
    $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        echo "gotcha";
    } 

    //validate page number is really numaric
    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');}

    //get current starting point of records
    $position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

    //Limit our results within a specified range. 
    $results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM user_registration_details WHERE email = '$email' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");

    //output results from database
    echo '<ul class="page_result">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["id"].'. <span class="page_name">'.$row["contact_name"].'</span><span class="page_message">'.$row["email"].'</span><span class="view"><a href="viewmore.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">    View Details</a></span></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';


    ?>
```

Please the code above is getting the user email from the URL and also successfully inputting it into the JavaScript variable dude. Also all the AJAX pagination script is working perfectly as I want it just that I can't send the user email to fetch_pages.php to be able to restrict the search based a particular user email. please how can I send the user email details to fetch_pages without refreshing the page and not still disturbing the pagination script. please all help will be needed as I need the script for a major project.

Answer (score 0):

i came to understand that the only problem was to add dude to the javascript code as below.
the same webpage cannot send two ajax request to the same php at the same time.

```
$("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0, 'email':(dude)}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load

        $(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {

            $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');

            var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
            var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need 

            $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class

            //post page number and load returned data into result element
            //notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
            $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':(page_num-1),'email':(dude)}, function(){

            });
```